# Facebook removes parameters from url that I used to sendusing facebook send button

Tags: facebook, parameters, facebook-social-plugins

Facebook removes parameters from url that I used to send using facebook send button.

I have tested my url http://www.logixsolution.info/grouppay/gift/?og_id=1 in http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug there also this same problem exists. I have checked with encoded url, but still the problem exists.[image]

Check attached screenshot of debug result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the bottom of the debug result screenshot you added - it's showing that when accessing `http://www.logixsolution.info/grouppay/gift?og_id=1` there was

- a HTTP 301 redirect to `http://www.logixsolution.info/grouppay/gift/?og_id=1`
- a canonical URL redirect from there  to `http://www.logixsolution.info/grouppay/gift/` -

The final URL in the chain is `http://www.logixsolution.info/grouppay/gift/` and this is the one the tags are read from

I tested manually and got this too:
`<link rel='canonical' href='http://www.logixsolution.info/grouppay/gift/' />` 
Set the canonical URL either there or in the `og:url` meta tag to be the URL you want the likes/comments/etc to be attributed to and the meta tags to be read from

Comment: But when I tried with this http://www.logixsolution.info/grouppay/gift/?og_id=1 url there was no redirection as you said. But the result was same as previous. I have placed multiple urls like this http://www.logixsolution.info/grouppay/gift/?og_id=1 http://www.logixsolution.info/grouppay/gift/?og_id=2 http://www.logixsolution.info/grouppay/gift/?og_id=3 with send button in same page. So how could I use og:url with these in the same page??

Comment: set the og:url to the URL whose tags you want read, and make sure that that page returns the right tags, you probably want `http://www.logixsolution.info/grouppay/gift/?og_id=2` to have an og:url tag of `http://www.logixsolution.info/grouppay/gift/?og_id=2` and the meta tags for gift '2'